# Limit on heap size

Tags: java, c, memory, heap-memory

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the C/C++ heap has no limit, you do not need to pass any argument to increase it.

So why java has a limit on the heap?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that Java has a garbage collector and neither C nor C++ do.

Comment: @Rufflewind something what... but why you need to limit it? why just no let it blast the memory

Comment: C/C++ heap does have a limit. The limit of installed memory/available virtual memory. Whichever comes first. Java has a more interesting limit because of the GC but it does grow as needed until out of memory. Just as any other program would.

Comment: oh, so this limit, and the arguments for increasing it, are for the GC? now it make sense

Comment: Java VM is "safe". It creates sandbox for program. So when you star VM you can define maximal limits for space (Xmx and Xms options). That will prevent server from allocating too much space and will crush VM and not whole server. For example, Erlang web server will eat all memory if needed and can hang down computer which will lead to reboot, but JMV will not, so you can easily restart it with script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons:

- first you have the minimum heap size, which is there to prevent slow startup
- the max heap size is there so that the GC knows when to start doing it's job, without it it would be much harder (but doable, you would just need to take into account different heuristics like number of allocations etc.)
- the max heap size also prevents the JVM from hogging all the resources on the machine, which can be a really good thing